# How can I escape apostrophes in my SQL statement?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, escaping

Not to get into a discussion about SQL injection and sanitizing and etc...

For various reasons, I am doing the unspeakable and building and executing a dynamic SQL query WITHOUT using query params.

So... I'm building a list of columns and a list of values, and then I have the following code:

```
insertRecord.setSql("INSERT INTO MyTable(" & columns & ") VALUES(" & values & ")");
```

This works properly for most records, but for a few records one of the string field values has an apostrophe or single quote:

```
'SHERIFF'S OFFICE'
```

This is giving me the SQL error: `Incorrect syntax near 'S'.`

I have tried using preserve single quotes in several ways and it doesn't help:

```
insertRecord.setSql("INSERT INTO MyTable(" & columns & ") VALUES(" & preserveSingleQuotes(values) & ")");
```

OR

```
insertRecord.setSql(PreserveSingleQuotes("INSERT INTO MyTable(" & columns & ") VALUES(" & values & ")"));
```

Is there any way to escape all the apostrophes, or otherwise format my sql string properly, other than using a `ReplaceNoCase(colValue, "'", "''")` on each value individually as I'm building the string (which does work)?

Comment: Can't you escape it with a backslash ie `'SHERIFF\'S OFFICE'`?

Comment: @Cyclone - You can escape it with doubled single quotes, but the values are coming from a dynamic source so I would need to do a replace to start adding it to each value. I'm looking for a built-in function that would sort of sanitize/format my sql statement before passing it to sql server, similar to what cfqueryparam does.

Comment: Did you try doing a single replacement of all the apostrophe's after the entire string is processed, or will that mess up single quotes surrounding string values?

Comment: What you are attempting to do is such a bad idea (and you recognize this), I don't even want to help you be successful in your endeavor to implement it. I have seen ad-hoc queries for running `select` queries, but never for running `insert` queries. You are setting yourself up for a nightmare of support when things go wrong...and they will go wrong.

Comment: *You are setting yourself up for a nightmare of support* Absolutely. The choice is yours, but I have worked with apps that make heavy use of dynamic sql. Constructing and debugging those queries was *always* more of a hassle than with parametrized sql. Case in point, this question.

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion? Oh, and I agree with @Leigh, and your own trepidation suggesting you are aware this is likely a foolhardy exercise from the outset.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of the syntax for the `setSql` statement but perhaps you are missing single quotes around your string values. Have you tried adding those?

What I mean is this. Assuming the SQL statement needs to look something like this (notice the quotes around each value):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable 
(column1, column2, column3) 
VALUES 
('value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3')
```

Then the `setSql` statement should look like:

```
insertRecord.setSql("INSERT INTO MyTable (column1, column2, column3) VALUES ('value 1', 'value 2', 'value 3')");
```

So you could try something like (notice the single quotes around the values):

```
insertRecord.setSql("INSERT INTO MyTable(" & columns & ") VALUES('" & preserveSingleQuotes(values) & "')");
```

You might also need to loop over every `values` in order to enclose each within the single quotes.

Comment: This doesn't really address the apostrophe problem.

Comment: The `preserveSingleQuotes()` function addresses the apostrophe problem. I am suggesting that the `values` may need to be included within single quotes for the `setSql` statement.

Comment: I haven't done so recently, but I have vague recollections of being unsuccessful with this approach.

Comment: I very secure solution is to replace ' against \' with the replace function and then - for advances security reasons - do a rereplace with a regex. we often use something like
<cfif rereplace(userinputvalue, application.securecharacters, "", "ALL") NEQ "">...(don't do query)...<cfelse> ... do query... </cfif>
having 
application.securecharacters = "[a-zA-Z0-9\+\_\-\ &\(\)\/öäüÖÄÜîôâéèÉÈûëçÇÿûÛùÙôœÔÏïÇæàÀß,\xfe]+"
this only allows the characters in your securitystring ;-)

Comment: the basic concept should always be disallow all and allow specific, not allow all and exclude specific.